# Using Images.xcassets in Xcode 6 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, xcasset

I have a project where I use Images.xcassets to organize my image resources. After update to Xcode 6 beta no image is displayed when the application runs. It looks like Xcode can't find path.

I found a temporary solution – old way:

1. Add folder with images to the project tree
2. Use initialization like [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]

So, what's wrong with xcassets in Xcode 6?

Comment: Marked. I met the same problem. After reading your post, I reopened Xcode 5, all runs well. It looks that beta version is just used for test.

Comment: @AlexEdunov try something from [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443306/accidentally-removed-xcassets-file-from-xcode-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is Xcode6-Beta bug.
I use it normally in Xcode5.
goog luck

Comment: Yes, in the current version I didn't achieve stable work and moved to the old version.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `.png` suffix of the image.
Just the image name is enough