# Can't see image of button in tableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UIButton` in my `tableView`, I am trying to change it's image, but when I run the app - in the simulator and in the iPhone, it shows nothing.

My **image** format is **PNG**.

Here is my code in `cellForRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! notesTableViewCell
        cell.buttonImage.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagetest2.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.buttonImage.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        cell.buttonImage.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.buttonImage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonImageFunc), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

        return cell
    }
```

This is `notesTableViewCell` code:

```
class notesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var buttonImage: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
   }
```

Comment: Do you actually see the button in the table view if you set a constant background color to it?

Comment: @arvidurs Yes, when I set backgroundColor and also when I just put text.

Comment: Whats the size of the png? try setting up 2x 3x resolutions, and default size of 32px by 32px

Comment: Are you sure you are including the imagetest2.png in your target?  Just having it in the project isn't enough.

Comment: Also, malformed pngs can cause this as well.  More details can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11001163/3708242.  Of course, I would higly recommend using Image Sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: Go to `Assets.xcassets` in your project. then create New Image Set with name `imagetest`. after that drag and drop `imagetest2.png` into sample image set
>   
>  please check button type: `.custom`

```
cell.buttonImage.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagetest"), for: .normal)
```

Comment: Well, it worked, but i did a stupid mistake and erased Assets.xcassets. I put it back again and now it doesn't work -_-

Comment: Clean project by cmd-option-shift-k.

Comment: This one helped solve the deleting Assets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443306/accidentally-removed-xcassets-file-from-xcode-project

Comment: But, why does this work, and my code didn't? everywhere around the web I found codes like I did and it worked for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
cell.buttonImage.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagetest2.png"), for: .normal)
cell.buttonImage.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

Also, try without content mode. Once

```
//cell.buttonImage.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, Go to your tableviewcell, select your button and in property section, select type custom.

[image]

Hope it will work.

Comment: Do you have image with this name "imagetest2.png" ?

Comment: I can't, it gets and error because I made the button not programmatically. But in the main storyboard its on custom