# Flutter - iOS Launch screen not loading properly

Tags: ios, image, png, flutter, transparency

I'm trying to make a new launch screen for the iOS version of my app debug.

When the app loads I expect to see the image below, **labeled A**, but instead I see image **B**

If you look at image B from a low angle, you can see a white spot on the screen. I assume this means that the LaunchImage worked, but obviously there's a problem with the image itself (**a .png file**). I think this is a problem with transparency with the image but I'm not sure why its occuring.

If I could get any information on why this is happening, even if its just a confirmation that this kind of image isn't supported that would be great.

**A**

[image]

**B**

[image]

Here's an image of my launch screen xib;

[image]

Comment: check your launch screen xib and add a screenshot

Comment: Done :) I've added the image at the bottom of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, you have to change the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file from your iOS project , not the `LaunchImage`.png.

Locate your ios folder and open the `Runner.xcworkspace` file using Xcode.

I wrote a complete post about that topic if you want more information : https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-splash-screen-9f4e05542548

Comment: I'm trying this method and it seemed promising until I accidently deleted **Assets.xcassets**. I've replaced it with an identical file that's showing in finder but not xcode. Do you know how I can re generate this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443306/accidentally-removed-xcassets-file-from-xcode-project

Comment: Once I've done this, how do I then move the image from the new file to LaunchScreen.storyboard for use?

Comment: Open assets file, drag in your image.  Open launchscree  , add uiimageview , select your image

Comment: I still don't understand how to add the uiimageview. It wasn't originally in my project and that didn't seem to make any discernible difference. All I need to know now is how to move the image from **assets.xcassets** to LaunchScreen.storyboard > View Controller Scene > View Controller > View > **This is where I need to move the image**

Comment: this is pure iOS question, not flutter.  Inside your view,  add an UIImageView component, then on the attributes check the image that you have in assets.  this is what you want: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/8832822120872f3d1f33a1996395a0dfcf285a49/68747470733a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f3964795a42664e2e676966

Comment: Okay great I finally figured it out! Thanks for the help

Comment: What if i want fullscreen images for different devices in landscape too. how is that possible.